# How to automatically add text in the ACF field when a user purchased a product? (PHP/Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

There is a custom post named 'project' and has acf fields. 
The tile of the each post is user name.
user name is from logged in users' email id.
Eg, post title is jeff (jeff@gmail.com).
When a user Jeff purchased a product, I need to automatically add ‘50’ in the ACF field ‘field_690d1eis5xx89’ of the Jeff post.

The code to check whether a user purchased a product or not, works well:

```
function has_bought( $value = 0 ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $value === 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    
    // Based on user ID (registered users)
    if ( is_numeric( $value) ) { 
        $meta_key   = '_customer_user';
        $meta_value = $value == 0 ? (int) get_current_user_id() : (int) $value;
    } 
    // Based on billing email (Guest users)
    else { 
        $meta_key   = '_billing_email';
        $meta_value = sanitize_email( $value );
    }
    
    $paid_order_statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

    $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $paid_order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '%s'
        AND pm.meta_value = %s
        LIMIT 1
    ", $meta_key, $meta_value ) );

    // Return a boolean value based on orders count
    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

This code doesn't update 50 to the acf field of the logged in user's post after the user purchased a product.
I tried both title and post_title but it still doesn't update.
I'm not sure but, maybe due to the $post->ID?

```
if( has_bought() ){
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_id = $current_user->display_name;
 // query to get a post with the user
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'project',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'title' =>$current_user_id
  ); // end $args
$query = new WP_Query($args);
 // if posts are returned, update field
 if ($query->have_posts()) {
    global $post;
update_field('field_690d1eis5xx89', '50', $post->ID);
} else {
return;
}
  } // end if have_posts
```

I’m a beginner, would you please help me?
Thank you

Comment: Try Post ID in the place of `$current_user_id` since `update_field()` function is looking for it `update_field($selector, $value, $post_id);`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.. I think 'acf/save_post' is a wrong one. I need to add 50 to the acf field key when the logged in user purchased a product, not saved a post.. I tried acf/render_field but still doesn't work..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you please [edit] your question and clarify? What happens when you run the code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].

Comment: I updated the question. Would you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation the `update_field` function accepts three parameter i.e. `$selector` `$value` and `$post_id` but it looks like in you code you are using `$current_user_id` which I think might not work.

Try to add `$post_id` in place of `$current_user_id`

Check: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Can I ask a question? I need to update 50 to the acf field  when the logged in user purchased a product, not saved a post. I think 'acf/save_post' is a wrong one as well. I tried acf/render_field but still doesn't work. Would you please let me know how to deal with this?